# How do I install a WatchGuard Deep Packet Inspection root certificate onto a Ubuntu Linux workstation?

Tags: networking, 16.04, ssl

I have a Ubuntu 16.04 workstation behind a WatchGuard firewall doing deep packet inspection. How do I add the DPI root certificate to the workstation in order to not be constantly told all the certificates are invalid?

Answer (score 1):

Download the certificate from the firewall's certificate portal website. You can find it at the address below. Replace firewall.ip.addr.ess with your firewalls IP.

```
http://firewall.ip.addr.ess:4126/certportal
```

If you don't know your firewall IP, it is a good chance that it is your default gateway. Use this command to find your default gateway.

```
netstat -nr |egrep ^0.0.0.0|awk '{print $2}'
```

Make a directory in your local root certificate store to put your certificate into and move the file in being sure the certificate extension is changed to *.crt.

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/wg-dpi/
sudo cp ~/Downloads/ProxyCA.cer /usr/local/share/ca-certificate/wg-dpi/watchguard-dpi.crt
```

Update your Certificate Authority store. The command output should confirm adding one certificate.

```
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

You should see something like this at the end of the output.

```
Certificate added: O=WatchGuard_Technologies, OU=Fireware, CN=Fireware HTTPS Proxy (SN 80DA00F0B0000 2016-19-77 22:46:25 UTC) CA
1 new root certificates were added to your trust store.
```

## If you are using the Chrome web browser

- In chrome, enter the URL:  chrome://settings/advanced
- Select "Manage Certificates" Button
- Click "Authoritities" Tab
- Click "Import" button
- Enter "/usr/local/share/ca-certificate/wg-dpi/watchguard-dpi.crt"
- Select "Open"
- Select "Done"
- Restart Chrome